# Regex.Replace, String.Replace or StringBuilder.Replace which is the fastest?

Tags: .net, performance, string

I need to replace all `System.Environment.Newline(s)` in the string returned by my function with `System.Environment.Newline + \t` (as I am trying to apply indenting) and I need to do this several times.

My question is which one is the most efficient way to do this?

I know that `StringBuilder` is faster than `String.Replace` but I dont know about `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: Already benchmarks by Debugging Toolbox http://blogs.msdn.com/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance.aspx

Comment: Thanks Shay due to the benchmark sting.replace is the best one . 
PS : if somebody wants t read the article I suggest read all comments cause they didn't do a correct test at first place .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're just trying to do it within a single string, I'd expect `string.Replace` to be as fast as anything else. `StringBuilder` is useful when you want to perform a number of *separate* steps and want to avoid creating an intermediate string on each step.

Have you benchmarked `string.Replace` to find out whether or not it's fast enough for you?

I would personally only start using regular expressions when I was actually dealing with a pattern, rather than just a fixed sequence of characters. If the performance of this is absolutely crucial, you could benchmark that as well of course.

Answer (score 3):

Compiled Regex will be faster, however, unless the string is massive and is being run on a myriad of strings, `String.Replace()` is the way to go for the sake of readability.