# regex vs string replace

Tags: regex, string, str-replace

Actually I've used regex pattern on url to replace its string.
I tried to replace the "www." from the url.
Now, I would like to know that is there any benefit or problem to use regex pattern instead to put that exact string.

For example,
     sting.replace("/w{3}./","")    vs string.replace("www.","");

I am asking about the topic like execution time.

Comment: Which language? Also, please include valid syntax.. Anyway, generally one would use a regular expression when a literal string replacement *wouldn't* work. The biggest downside of a regular expression, IMOHO, is accidental forgetting to escape special characters (as shown) - especially if it comes from user input. "Performance" is usually irrelevant.

Comment: `string.replace` won't take regex as an argument.

Comment: hmm the `.` in question would be a metacharacter if not escaped :)

Comment: For .net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620410/regex-replace-string-replace-or-stringbuilder-replace-which-is-the-fastest